# Is there a library to parse data from Pig output in within Pig stream using Python?

Tags: python, streaming, apache-pig

If I have a Pig relation `aRelation` of type `{A:chararray,B:double}` which is passed through Pig streaming like:

```
C = STREAM aRelation THROUGH `python test.py`;
```

data will be processed line by line as strings. Is there a library to parse serialized Pig data in Python which would perform casting, conversion to complex types, etc.